# weird outlier in a cox regression model

Tags: regression, survival, outliers, cox-model, martingale

[image]

I'm using normal deviate residual to identify outliers, and I'm confused that my plot seems to suggest that there are unreasonably a lot of outliers...? Has anyone seen something like this?

```
pred.Surv<-exp(-predict(cox2,type="expected"))
nd.res<-qnorm(pred.Surv)
nd.res<- data.frame(nd.res=nd.res, lp=pred.lp)
```

I've also tried using survBootOutliers package,

```
outlier<-survBootOutliers(surv.object = Surv(time=data$$time, event=data$status),
                          covariate.data=data[,c(30:33)],
                          sod.method="deviance")
```

but I think it just identifies all data as outliers....

Comment: You haven't included the code that produces `cox2`, but I imagine you did not use a model that assumes normally distributed errors. Survival times are non-negative and usually skewed, so why would you expect them to be conditionally normal?

Comment: Sorry! cox2 was a multilevel model: coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ scale(gre) + scale(se)+ cluster(sid), data); but isn't this a common way of identifying outliers with survival data?? would you recommend not doing this?? thanks a lot!